# Remove labels in printer friendly version of books

Tags: nodes, entities

Is there any way to remove labels or apply a CSS file to the printer-friendly version of books?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I approached the problem:
Copied

```
/modules/book/book-node-export-html.tpl.php
/modules/book/book-export-html.tpl.php
```

to my theme directory and modified the *$contents* variable via str_replace.

This works fine as a temporary fix, but I guess performance-wise this is not the best solution, would would be still nice to find a way to apply CSS.